# How can I simulate a Cisco router LAN card failure?

Tags: cisco, snmp

I need to simulate cisco router 10k family LAN card failure in order to generate SNMP Traps. What steps I need to perform for this simulation. How can I find right OID values for different card models ????

Answer (score 1):

If you have physical access to the router, pulling out the line card should generate some, if not all, of the traps you are looking for.

I should mention that I have never seen a line card fail such that the device takes the card offline during operation.  I have seen them generate errors and act erratically but never outright fail.  Boot-up diagnostics may detect a failed/failing card but I'm not sure how you would simulate that sort of situation.

Comment: If I pull out the card, is there any chance, I will damage it?

Comment: While there is always the chance, the cards are supposed to be hot-swappable and I've inserted/pulled cards on multiple occasions without issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need the exact product model number to work out which ones you need, but Cisco have an [ISO MIB locator](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/MIBS/servlet/index) as well as an [SNMP Object Navigator](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/SearchOID.do?local=en&step=1). These will hopefully help you find what you're looking for.